# How to print a field data from the current node after webform (block) submitted successfully without refreshing the page (webform ajax)?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module's block on a custom content type.

The webform has some text fields and I passed some data from my custom content type fields to webform fields as explained [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/167361/34116).

I'm also using the [Webform Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax) module for webform submission.

What I want to do is to print some field data from the current node after webform (successful) submission.

I tried to use the **webform-confirmation-2.tpl.php** to do what I want *(2 is the node id of webform)*:

### Method #1

At first, I tried the method explained [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1515548):

```
<?php
  // Print the webform submission to the submitter
  include_once drupal_get_path('module','webform') . '/includes/webform.submissions.inc';
  $submission = webform_get_submission($node->nid, $sid);
  $email = NULL;
  $format = "html";
  print webform_submission_render($node, $submission, $email, $format);
?>
```

*It didn't work.*

```
(Notice: include() (../webform-confirmation-2.tpl.php line: 37) Array to string conversion.)
```

line 37 is:   `print webform_submission_render($node, $submission, $email, $format);`

### Method #2

And another [code](https://www.drupal.org/node/1515548#comment-8530319) in the same page *didn't work*:

```
<?php
    //lets see if we can show them their submission
    $sid = $_GET['sid'];
    if(isset($sid)){
        include_once drupal_get_path('module','webform') . '/includes/webform.submissions.inc';
        $submission = webform_get_submission($node->nid, $sid);
        $email = NULL;
        $format = "html";
        print render(webform_submission_render($node, $submission, $email, $format));
    }
?>
```

It gives this error: `Notice: include() (.../webform-confirmation-2.tpl.php line: 34) Undefined index: sid.`

line 34 is: `$sid = $_GET['sid'];`

**EDIT**: I solved the error, it doesn't give an error now but also doesn't give the *wanted result*.

### Method #3

Then, I tried to use [menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) in webform-confirmation-2.tpl.php:

```
<?php
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
        $print ($node->field_custom_field['und'][0]['value']);
    }
?>
```

*This also didn't work.* Nothing printed, no error.

### Method #4

I tried to print the field as a block inside of the webform-confirmation-2.tpl.php by using the [Field as Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock) module:

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('fieldblock', 'block_view', '7f1bb640a56605ca4ea56453ebf4c759');
print render($block['content']);
?>
```

*That code also didn't work. It didn't print anything.*

#### How to print a field data from the current node after webform (block) submitted successfully without refreshing the page (webform ajax)?

*Maybe another way to do that is to hide the fields (via CSS, JS etc.) at first and then if the webform submission done show them. Here, I have to know the trigger to use in the JavaScript but don't know.*

Comment: Any suggestion?